# Offline pip installation

Tags: python, pip, redhat

How can I install pip in an offline server?
I have SSH access and can send files via scp. The server has Red Hat.

I did this https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing.html#install-pip but tries to download something.

Is there a way to package pip and all its dependencies, so then I can send that to the server and install it from there? I already did this with python packages that to install with pip.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Download python-pip yum package. [pip RHEL install](http://sharadchhetri.com/2014/05/30/install-pip-centos-rhel-ubuntu-debian/), [yum download package](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/10154)
2. Move it to your offline machine
3. Yum it

Answer (score 0):

If the server has `python` installed, you can dowload `pip` wheel file, and run `python </path/to/pip.whl>:pip install --no-index --find-links=<pip.whl_dir> pip.whl` to install `pip` first. Then, you can download other pacakges, make a requirement file, and install them  with `pip install --no-deps --no-index --find-links=<package.whls_dir> -r requirements.txt`.