# How Install python-pip on Centos 7 with no internet

Tags: python, linux, repository, yum, epel

I need to simply be able to run: `yum-y install python-pip`, however I don't have internet connection on this machine.

Here is my current repo I have in /etc/yum.repos.d

```
[base]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Base
baseurl=http://dnsAdress/centos/$releasever/os/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7

#released updates
[updates]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Updates
baseurl=http://dnsAdress/centos/$releasever/updates/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7

#additional packages that may be useful
[extras]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Extras
baseurl=http://dnsAdress/centos/$releasever/extras/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7

#contrib - packages by Centos Users
[contrib]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Contrib
baseurl=http://dnsAdress/centos/$releasever/contrib/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
enabled=0
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7
```

SO now I install epel-release in order to install python-pip

So then the /etc/yum.repos.d has two more .repo files after install epel-release which are shown below:

**epel.repo** contents:

```
[epel]
name=Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 7 - $basearch
baseurl=http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/$basearch
#metalink=https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=epel-7&arch=$basearch
failovermethod=priority
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-EPEL-7

[epel-debuginfo]
name=Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 7 - $basearch - Debug
baseurl=http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/$basearch/debug
#metalink=https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=epel-debug-7&arch=$basearch
failovermethod=priority
enabled=0
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-EPEL-7
gpgcheck=1

[epel-source]
name=Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 7 - $basearch - Source
baseurl=http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/SRPMS
#metalink=https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=epel-source-7&arch=$basearch
failovermethod=priority
enabled=0
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-EPEL-7
gpgcheck=1
```

**epel-testing.repo** contents

```
[epel-testing]
name=Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 7 - Testing - $basearch
baseurl=http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/testing/7/$basearch
#metalink=https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=testing-epel7&arch=$basearch
failovermethod=priority
enabled=0
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-EPEL-7

[epel-testing-debuginfo]
name=Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 7 - Testing - $basearch - Debug
baseurl=http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/testing/7/$basearch/debug
#metalink=https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=testing-debug-epel7&arch=$basearch
failovermethod=priority
enabled=0
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-EPEL-7
gpgcheck=1

[epel-testing-source]
name=Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 7 - Testing - $basearch - Source
baseurl=http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/testing/7/SRPMS
#metalink=https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=testing-source-epel7&arch=$basearch
failovermethod=priority
enabled=0
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-EPEL-7
gpgcheck=1
```

My problem is that because I don't have internet I get an error with the baseurl in the epel.repos file

Heres the error:

```
http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] curl#7 - "Failed to connect to 2605:bc80:3010:600:dead:beef:cafe:feda: Network is unreachable"
```

So How can I install python-pip on this machine without needing internet??

Comment: Do you have another computer (with working internet) you could install it on, then transfer the files over?

Comment: `pip` is 100% internet based. Why would you like to install `pip` if you don't have internet, or how do you plan to use `pip`?

Comment: @Kwahn I have a windows computer with internet and can transfer files over if needed.

Comment: @ImanolLuengo this is a server being used as a deployed station for openstack and is only on my internal network.

Comment: Presume you can plug a USB key or something into the machine you want pip on? You can download the files you need from a number of places then transfer over

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32322697/3749021