# How to upgrade pip offline

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, yum

I have machine with CentOS 7.9 and pip version `pip 9.0.3 from /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages (python 3.6)`.

I need to install on my machine `impacket`. But installation fails because pip is too old.
So I upgrade pip with command

`pip3 install --upgrade pip` and after that everything works perfectly fine.

The problem is that I make it when my machine is connected to internet. My customer's machine is not connected to internet. So I need to update all the stuff offline.

My plan was to:

- download 2 packages: `impacket` and last version of `pip`.
- send these files to customer's machine.
- upgrade `pip` offline.
- install `impacket` offline.

The first thing that I'm stuck with, is to upgrate pip. Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32321927/offline-pip-installation) advice I tried to download pip with `yum`, using this command:

`yum install --downloadonly python3-pip -y`

But I get such result and nothing happens:

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centos.spd.co.il
 * epel: mirror.dogado.de
 * extras: centos.spd.co.il
 * updates: centos.spd.co.il
Package python3-pip-9.0.3-8.el7.noarch already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

Or with command `yum upgrade --downloadonly python3-pip -y` also nothing happens:

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centos.spd.co.il
 * epel: mirror.dogado.de
 * extras: centos.spd.co.il
 * updates: centos.spd.co.il
No packages marked for update
```

How can I implement my plan? (or maybe there is a better plan?)

Comment: This is pretty interesting. I wonder why you can’t download the package using older versions of pip… so you can’t just copy over the impacket package and install it with the local version of pip?

Comment: If you're installating impacket offline, you'll have to download all the dependencies beforehand as well; and their dependencies, and so on.

Comment: You didn't specify anything about the offline machine. Is it the same OS, same architecture? Because then you could just copy-paste your installation to that machine.

Comment: @Drphoton, instalation of this package gives me error: `UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'cffi_modules'` .. some stuff ... `rustc: n/a`. As I understood, installation requires to compile something. And compiler is absent. New version stores wheels (that are also not exist in old version) so on new pip compilation is not needed and package is successfully installed.

Comment: @9769953, customer has same machine. But I have a lot of customers and can't copypaste installation to all of them. I actually need to provide upgrade mechanism/patch that they will run and this patch should do all the stuff.

Comment: @9769953, yes I understand that I should mess with dependencies. Do you have better solution?

Comment: Copy a virtual environment from your setup. That is one copy from a USB drive per machine. Any other mechanism would involve grabbing the software from somewhere else, which means downloading it.

Comment: Are the machines on the same internal network?

Comment: @9769953, could I copy virtual environment from my setup and on customers' machines replace global environment vith this copy? P.S. all machines are on different networks.

Comment: "on customers' machines replace global environment": that would be a bad idea. The idea of a virtual environment is that you don't have to touch the OS packages themselves, while at a user level, you still get the new packages. Potentially, if there are multiple users per machine, you can set up a separate directory, in something like `/opt/local/` where you copy your v-env, then make sure PATH and PYTHONPATH (and possibly LD_LIBRARY_PATH) are properly set up.

Answer (score 0):

To upgrade pip do thefollowing steps (Windows):

on the machine with internet

1. create a folder that will contain an offline download of the pip package
2. open the command line and cd to the created folder
3. run: pip download -r requirements.txt
   where requirements.txt file content is only one line "pip"
4. copy the folder to the offline machine
5. on the offline machine open the command line and cd to copied folder
6. run: pip install --no-index --find-links path\to\copied\folder -r requirements.txt
7. run: python -m pip install --upgrade pip

Step 6 will fail but continue to step 7 (maybe step 6 is unnecessary)